# LINQ Distinct operator, ignore case?

Tags: c#, linq, string, comparison, distinct

Given the following simple example:

```
    List<string> list = new List<string>() { "One", "Two", "Three", "three", "Four", "Five" };

    CaseInsensitiveComparer ignoreCaseComparer = new CaseInsensitiveComparer();

    var distinctList = list.Distinct(ignoreCaseComparer as IEqualityComparer<string>).ToList();
```

It appears the CaseInsensitiveComparer is not actually being used to do a case-insensitive comparison.

In other words **distinctList**  contains the same number of items as **list**.   Instead I would expect, for example, "Three" and "three" be considered equal.

Am I missing something or is this an issue with the Distinct operator?

Answer (score 287, accepted):

`StringComparer` does what you need:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() {
    "One", "Two", "Three", "three", "Four", "Five" };

var distinctList = list.Distinct(
    StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase).ToList();
```

(or invariant / ordinal / etc depending on the data you are comparing)

Answer (score 5):

[See Marc Gravells answer if you want the most concise approach]

After some investigation and good feedback from Bradley Grainger I've implemented the following IEqualityComparer. It suports a case insensitive Distinct() statement  (just pass an instance of this to the Distinct operator) :

> ```
> class IgnoreCaseComparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
> {
>     public CaseInsensitiveComparer myComparer;
>
>     public IgnoreCaseComparer()
>     {
>         myComparer = CaseInsensitiveComparer.DefaultInvariant;
>     }
>
>     public IgnoreCaseComparer(CultureInfo myCulture)
>     {
>         myComparer = new CaseInsensitiveComparer(myCulture);
>     }
>
>     #region IEqualityComparer<string> Members
>
>     public bool Equals(string x, string y)
>     {
>         if (myComparer.Compare(x, y) == 0)
>         {
>             return true;
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             return false;
>         }
>     }
>
>     public int GetHashCode(string obj)
>     {
>         return obj.ToLower().GetHashCode();
>     }
>
>     #endregion
> }
> ```

Comment: You simply don't need this. See my reply.

Comment: Yes, your reply arrived just as I was clicking "Post Your Answer".

Comment: They were certainly with <20 seconds of each other, I recall. Still, implementing something like IEqualityComparer<T> is still a useful exercise, if only for understanding how it works...

Comment: Thanks again,  I'll let this this answer live then, unless anyone strongly objects.

Comment: This sample fails when initialized for the tr-TR culture if the current culture is en-US, because GetHashCode will report different values for  I (U+0049) and ı (U+0131), whereas Equals will consider them equal.

Answer (score 3):

---

```
 ## Distinct Operator( Ignoring Case) ##
  string[] countries = {"USA","usa","INDIA","UK","UK" };

  var result = countries.Distinct(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

  foreach (var v in result) 
  { 
  Console.WriteLine(v);
  }
```

**OutPut will Be**

```
   USA 
   INDIA
   UK
```

Comment: Please avoid posting code snippets without explanation. Edit your answer and add a body to it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a far simpler version.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "One", "Two", "Three", "three", "Four", "Five" };

var z = (from x in list select new { item = x.ToLower()}).Distinct();

z.Dump();
```