# System.NotSupportedException This overload of the method 'System.Linq.Queryable.GroupBy' is currently not supported.'

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

```
public partial class GoodsCode_EAN
{
    public string GoodsCode { get; set; }
    public string EAN { get; set; }
}
```

This is model where GoodsCode is unique every time but EAN not

```
var test = _context.GoodsCode_EAN
                        .FromSql($"SELECT * FROM dbo.fnGoodsCode_EAN({SavedData.Entities.id_cenoprov})")
                        .GroupBy(p => p.EAN, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                        .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList(), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

So I just try to group every elements with same EAN to dictionary and getting this exception...

> **System.NotSupportedException:**
>   'Could not parse expression 
>   value(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[ProfiKasa.Portal.Models.newModel.CisloZbozi_EAN]).FromSql("SELECT
>   * FROM dbo.fnCisloZbozi_EAN(1)", __p_0).GroupBy(p => p.EAN, __p_1)': This overload of the method 'System.Linq.Queryable.GroupBy' is
>   currently not supported.'

When I remove `ToDictionary` everything work...
Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Add .ToArray() before .ToDictionary() and test again

Comment: Same error again...

Comment: Does EF understand `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` ? I think `p.EAN.ToLower()` might help.

Comment: It is because of StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase in GroupBy. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047891/linq-using-stringcomparer-with-groupby-distinct-in-query-syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity framework doesn't undestand the `StringComparer` enumeration to begin with. Actually, it doesn't support the entire overload of `GroupBy` that takes a second parameter (`IEqualityComparer<T>`).

You can use `ToLower()` as an alternative because it is supported and can be translated into SQL:

```
.GroupBy(p => p.EAN.ToLower())
```

Comment: Thank you!
So one -

`.FromSql($"SELECT * FROM dbo.fnGoodsCode_EAN({SavedData.Entities.id_cenoprov})")
                        .GroupBy(p => p.EAN)
                        .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());`

Comment: Another solution is - 

`.FromSql($"SELECT * FROM dbo.fnGoodsCode_EAN({SavedData.Entities.id_cenoprov})")
                        .ToLookup(l => l.EAN)
                        .ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.ToList(), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);`