# Removing descrepancies from my list

Tags: c#, list

Hi there. I was hoping I could ask for some advice in regards to a problem I am struggling with.

I have a List with more than a thousand values and there are some duplicates, not exact duplicates but discrepencies based on upper and lower case. 
so for example I would have

**Training** and **training** in the same list or
**Vision and Values** and **Vision and values**.

So there are various instances where there are minor discrepies based on Case difference.

How could I go about in removing thsese 'excess' values?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283063/linq-distinct-operator-ignore-case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried this in LinqPad:

```
var list = new List<String> { "Hello", "World", "HELLO", "beautiful", "WORLD" };

var l = list.Distinct(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase).ToList();

Console.WriteLine(l);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Linq:

```
var listWithDups = new List<string>() = {"blah","Blah","etc","etc."};
var listWithoutDups = listWithDups.Distinct(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would add all entries to a [Hashset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359100.aspx)

A Hashset is a collection that stores maximum one of every item added to it.
You'd write a "ignore case" equity comparer that you'd pass into the Hashset construcor.
Like:

```
     var set = new Hashset( yourListWithDuplicates, (x,y) => x.Equals(y, 
StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
```