# list with distinct and StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase

Tags: c#

I have list, how can I get distinct values?

```
IList<string> words = new List<string> { "A", "b", "a" };
var distinctWords = words.Distinct(StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

this gives me error:
*Distinct has some invalid arguments.*

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ Distinct operator, ignore case?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283063/linq-distinct-operator-ignore-case)

Answer (score 14):

You need: [`StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.ordinalignorecase.aspx) not `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`

```
IList<string> words = new List<string> { "A", "b", "a" };
var distinctWords = words.Distinct(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```