# Remove duplicate strings in list using C# / LinQ but ignore case

Tags: c#, linq

With the list:

> "A", "Bb", "C", "a", "d", "bb"

How can I use LinQ to remove duplicates while ignoring casing?

the output here should be:

> "C", "d"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ Distinct operator, ignore case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283063/linq-distinct-operator-ignore-case)

Comment: yes, I think you're right. And the solution there is shorter too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this

```
  var result = testList
               .GroupBy(item => item, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
               .Where(g => g.Count() == 1)
               .Select(g => g.Key)
               .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use can use the GroupBy method with one of the IgnoreCase string comparers, then select only those groups consisting of a single element

```
.GroupBy(_ => _, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
.Where(_ => _.Count() == 1)
```

Comment: append `.Select(_ => _.Key).ToList();` to get the output the OP is after

Answer (score 0):

You can use GroupBy() with the StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase option as follows:

```
List<String> data = new List<String>() { "A", "Bb", "C", "a", "d", "bb" };
List<String> newData = data.GroupBy(x => x, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
    .Where(el => el.Count() == 1)
    .Select(el => el.Key)
    .ToList();
```